# TypeError: Cannot read properties of null (reading 'url') Nextjs

Tags: javascript, reactjs, next.js, graphql, hygraph

I'm studying from https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Dc7LAgqy1_E

I got this problem
I use hygraph to connect my blog website and at coverPhoto is a mistake

I tried to fix this as
t think my hygraph is not published but I already published it
also I copy API from youtube tutorial and it working for me
but my API is not working

```
<Image  src={coverPhoto.url} alt=""/>
```

and I use `` for `coverPhoto.url` image is not sent error but does not show image too.

I want the image to be shown on the website.

this is my API playground

```
 query{
  posts{
    title,
    datePublished
    coverPhoto{
      url
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: If it's the new Next Image component, it won't get displayed without a specified size. https://beta.nextjs.org/docs/optimizing/images#image-sizing

Comment: I used <img/> instead of <Image/>. I found that <Image/> causes a lot of problems.